# Android Studio 1.5 where put emulator options

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I cannot understand where I need to put emulator options to use kvm? After update to version 1.5 Run/Debug configuration emulator tab disappeared.

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: related bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195758

Comment: Thanks! I don't know about this bug.